# How to change the sings of a list of numbers

Tags: python

Hello I have a random list of numbers where you identify the major one and it gets divided by it self and for the other ones.. But I want that then the numbers that I get from the operation have a particular sign, for example: the variable a1 to be positive, b1 to be negative, c1 to be positive and so.
This is what I do:

```
a1 = -abs(signal1).max()
b1 = abs(signal2).max()
c1 = -abs(signal3).max()
d1 = abs(signal4).max()
e1 = -abs(signal5).max()
f1 = abs(signal6).max()

values = [a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]
max_value = float(max(values, key=abs))
values = [v/max_value for v in values]
a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 = values
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for using map:

```
l = [-1, 2, -3, 4, -5]
lr = map(lambda x: x * -1, l)
lr
>>[1, -2, 3, -4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list and multiply each number by -1.

```
for index in range(len(values)):
  values[index] *= -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Method one:

```
map(lambda x: x * -1, values)
```

Method two:

```
[-1 * i for i in values]
```

Comment: Or: `map(operator.neg, values)`

Comment: @JonClements don't you need to `import` it first?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import cycle

def amp(lst):
    return abs(max(lst, key=abs))

values = [amp(x)*sign for x,sign in zip([signal1, signal2, signal3, signal4, signal5, signal6], cycle([1, -1]))]
norm = float(amp(values))
values = [v/norm for v in values]
```